# Is this expected behavior: Integer vs Long in Apex

Tags: apex, data-types

I ran this code snippet in anonymous apex:

```
Integer slaM = 60000;

Long L1 = 60000 * slaM;

Long L2 = 60000 * (long) slaM;

system.debug ('L1: ' + L1 + ' /L2: ' + L2)
```

Here is the debug output:

DEBUG|L1: -694967296 / L2: 3600000000

So when I multiply a long with a long, the result is correct.  But when I multiply a long with an integer, and it reaches a certain size, it seems to be using the 2's complement of the number.  Is this expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. Multiplying two Integer values (`60000` is an Integer value, not a Long), results in an Integer (the upper 32-bits of the the result are truncated/lost), while multiplying an Integer by a Long causes the Integer to be automatically promoted to a Long, which calculates and outputs a Long result. You can force a literal long with the L suffix:

```
Integer slaM = 60000;
Long L1 = 60000L * slaM;
Long L2 = 60000 * (long) slaM;
```

Now, L1 and L2 will both have the same result, as the `slaM` in L1 is automatically promoted to a Long because `60000L` is a Long value.

Comment: Thanks Fox, that makes perfect sense.  What is strange is that this arose when I was calling BusinessHours.add method, which takes a Long as the final parameter.  I was passing in "60000 * slaM" as that parameter.  If, as you say, that is an integer, should it not have have resulted in a compile error, or at least a run time error?

Comment: @hamayoun No, because of automatic promotion. The two Integer values are multiplied, an Integer is returned (the upper 32-bits are discarded), then that Integer is promoted to a Long because that's what the parameter data type is. That's just how programming works, unfortunately. In your case, though, the fix is just adding an `L` to your code :D

Comment: After 30+ years, I still need to learn Programming 101 ;-)

Comment: If anyone is interested in the full story: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules